# Is there any way to compile a wireshark dissector plugin in Windows 7 without using QT?

Tags: python, c, qt, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have been writing a dissector of some protocol for wireshark in C language.I have successfully compiled its plugin in Linux.But I want to develop a plugin for windows too(dll file).All the posts related to wireshark plugin development innvolve the use of QT in compiling the plugin.But I was wondering if there could be some way that I can compile it without using QT because QT is required  for GUI and I dont need any gui for my plugin.I just want to use its dll file in wireshark.So if there is any way by which I can compile my plugin alone without compiling whole wireshark,It would be very helpful.
In short,I dont want to use QT for making plugin.So please suggest some way .I am really stuck on this problem .

Comment: Is there a reason that you have to make so many drastic changes going from Linux to Windows, aside from maybe switching out some libraries and compiling it differently?

Comment: Yaa..actually,I want to make it portable for distribution.And the people I have to distribute it prefer windows.So I want to make a plugin for windows

Comment: Given that building stuff under Qt is very easy - probably easier than without Qt - I don't quite understand why you even bother avoiding Qt. It's a nice framework.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing `-DBUILD_wireshark=OFF` to CMake as described in the Developer's Guide?